# Running Tableau in Canvas App

Tags: canvas

I am looking to embed a Tableau report inside one of our SFDC communities. I am planning on creating a separate tab inside of the community so that everybody has access to the report. Will each individual SFDC community users need their own Tableau Interactor account to view/filter the dashboard ?

Comment: That might be a better question for Tableau than us, no? I mean, perhaps someone here knows definitively, but I would think that Tableau would know better than us.

Comment: I have asked it there as well... Trying my luck.. if someone has done it before. I can get it from SF perspective..

Comment: That's definitely a reasonable approach. I hope you get the information you're looking for. If you happen to find out from them, feel free to self-answer.

Comment: Do you intend "an individual Tableau account/access" when you say -- Tableau Interactor account? I was recently trying to address an exact same use case of integrating Tableau in Salesforce with Canvas App, so I may have an answer to it if you can provide info on my question.